# Firebase admin SDK + Vue + Webpack,TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to setup the firebase admin sdk in my server running on Vue + Webpack. Here is procedure. then I got a error.

1. vue init webpack vue-firebase
2. npm install firebase-admin --save
3. Add some code into main.js like:

   ```
   var admin = require('firebase-admin');
   var serviceAccount = require('../config/firebase.json');
   admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
     databaseURL: 'https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com'
   });

   var database = admin.database();
   var ref = database.ref("users");
   ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val());
   }, function (errorObject) {
     console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
   });
   ```
4. npm run dev
5. Safari caught error: database.js:63

> TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function. (In 'rtdb.initStandalone(this.appInternal, dbUrl, version)', 'rtdb.initStandalone' is undefined)

Does anyone have a clue to fix it?

Comment: $ node -v
v8.11.3
$ vue --version
2.9.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use the Firebase Admin SDK in a vue.js web app. The vue code runs in the browser, not in the server.

From the [getting started with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) page: "The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from **privileged environments**..." A web app is not a privileged environment: if you put your service account into a web page, you're exposing your administrative credentials to all users of that web app.

You'll instead want to use the regular Web SDK of Firebase, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 0):

you can use `npm install firebase` instead of `npm install firebase-admin`. This package can very useful.